# How can I add my own include paths to Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm trying to add my own include paths into Arduino IDE so I can use my own libraries.

I've been working in a library that is present into my git repo, which is structured as follows:

```
apps
  project1
  project2
  project3
    project3.ino
    (other stuff)
libs
  mylib1
  mylib2
    lib2.h
    lib2.cpp
```

But using `#include "../../libs/mylib2/lib2.h"` into my .ino file, pops the error:

`fatal error: ../../libs/mylib2/lib2.h: No such file or directory #include "../../libs/mylib2/lib2.h"`

How can I add my own include paths for my own libraries without copying them into the Arduino libraries folder (I need to keep my code portable).

Also I work with VSCode (Ubuntu), so if you know any solution related to this editor, it would be great.

Most of projects in this repo were made with Arduino.

Thank you in advance.

I tried with absolute paths but it's not a solution for me. Need portability. Also tried with Arduino extension for VSCode but I didn't find any setting for that.